# using TBXML and parse an attribute that there isn't all the time

Tags: iphone, xml, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an xml file using TBXML.
my xml is like this:

```
<locations>
   <location>
      <id>1</id>
      <name>hello</name>
   </location>
   <location>
      ...
</locations>
```

all works fine, but there is a big problem: sometimes the xml can "skip" the "name" tag, so, for example, there is something like this:

```
...
</location>
<location>
   <id>43</id>
</location>
<location>
...
```

where is the problem?
that using this code

```
TBXMLElement *location = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"location" parentElement:root];
while (location){
   TBXMLElement *id = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"id" parentElement:location];
   TBXMLElement *name = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"name" parentElement:location];
   ... //do something
   location = location -> nextSibling;
}
```

the app crashes reading the tag "name" because sometimes there isn't...

How can i solve it??

thanks!

Comment: When you say "the app crashes", you need to post crash logs from the console if available. It would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

The app is probably crashing because your `... //do something` is assuming that `name` is none-nil. If the `<name>` element wasn't found in the XML, the `name` var in your code ends up being nil.

What is the code that you snipped out in the "do something" comment?

Btw, I found this info by googling for something like "tbxml check for child node existence" and finding the following page:

http://www.tbxml.co.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=12